# Add two values from two different Lists

Tags: c#

Again another one of those moments when my brain has completely failed me.

I am trying to add(Addition) two values(decimals) from two separate Lists. In all honesty i think I'm running into value type issues but any clarification welcome.

```
public List<decimal> getTotalSellingPrice(int costSheetID) 
{
    List<decimal> totalSellingPrice = new List<decimal>();

    decimal bothMarkupAndToms = 0;
    foreach (var i in getMarkupPrice(costSheetID)) 
    {
      foreach (var m in getToms(costSheetID)) 
      {
          bothMarkupAndToms = i + m;                      
      }


      totalSellingPrice.Add(Math.Round(bothMarkupAndToms));   
    }

    return totalSellingPrice;
}
```

As you can see for each item in each collection i want to add to another value within the nested collection.

So on each pass it should "i + m" then add to the final list ready for the UI.

Any help would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: and what is it doing instead? (only adding the last tom?)

Comment: So what are you seeing? You need to describe the problem, not just give us code...

Comment: Shouldn't `totalSellingPrice.Add(Math.Round(bothMarkupAndToms));` be inside the second loop? Else you'll just get the last calculated value in each increment of the first loop.

Comment: It's really unclear why you'd want to do this at all... can you describe the context in more detail? (It doesn't help that your names are somewhat hard to understand - what's a "tom"?) Note that unless anything odd is going on, you're going to have the same sum from all the "toms" for each iteration of the outer loop...

Comment: Your `bothMarkupAndToms = i + m; ` is totally worthless for all but the last value in `getToms(costSheetID)`. Do you need `bothMarkupAndToms += m;`?

Comment: @P5Coder - the variable name suggests that the OP doesn't need that (since you have removed `i`). Its unclear why every possible combination of markups and tom's needs to be added together to me so I don't know what is the correct answer but Kilazur seems closest to it

Comment: Apologies for the lack of details, i'll rectify this within the hour.

Comment: So the idea is to add the markup value and the toms(travel percentage 0.02%) value together to give a total cost. This should happen on each iteration. getMarkupPrice and getToms returns lists of decimals with accurate data. So i want to create a new list with those values added together. With the code above it is adding 20 from the toms to every value in the markup list. If i place the list add method inside the toms loop, it returns 16 values which there is only 4 values inside the markup and toms list. Hope this helps really difficult to explain.

Comment: @TezWingfield Please see my answer. I think that is the logic. Based on your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you the sum of each value from `getTotalSellingPrice()` with it's corresponding value from `getToms()`. If both the lists have 4 values each this will give you 4 values in the resulting list. What you were doing was more like permutation. This is proper addition of two lists.

```
public List<decimal> getTotalSellingPrice(int costSheetID)
{
    List<decimal> totalSellingPrice = new List<decimal>();
    List<object> toms = getToms(costSheetID);
    int j = 0,
        tomsCount = toms.Count;
    foreach (var i in getMarkupPrice(costSheetID))
    {
        if(j >= tomsCount )
            break;
        totalSellingPrice.Add(Math.Round(i + Convert.ToDecimal(toms[j])));
        j++;
    }

    return totalSellingPrice;
}
```

For each value in `getMarkupPrice()`, the above code is adding the corresponding value from `toms` (based on the index `j` it uses to track the current value in `toms`) and adding the result in the `totalSellingPrice` list. The additional `if` block inside the `foreach` checks if the `toms` is out of values. If yes, the `break;` statement just exits the execution of that `foreach` loop.

Comment: Hi, Absolutely fantastic. Worked like a dream! I'm just about to mark this as answered. But if i may, could you elaborate on your logic in detail? What's happening? Because i'm not sure how its getting the value from "toms" just based on a "count". Would be nice to fully understand this logic. Again Thank you.

Comment: @TezWingfield For each value in `getMarkupPrice()`, the above code is adding the corresponding value from `toms` (based on the index `j` it uses to track the current value in `toms`) and adding the result in the `totalSellingPrice` list. The additional `if` block inside the `foreach` checks if the `toms` is out of values. If yes, the `break;` statement just exits the execution of the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Much appreciated, took me a little time to grasp that the indexer (J) returns the value from it's index position. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to put an item (i+m) into the list, try the following:

```
public List<decimal> getTotalSellingPrice(int costSheetID) 
{
    List<decimal> totalSellingPrice = new List<decimal>();
    foreach (var i in getMarkupPrice(costSheetID))
    {
      foreach (var m in getToms(costSheetID))
      {
          totalSellingPrice.Add(Math.Round(i + m));
      }
    }
    return totalSellingPrice;
}
```

And if you want to out an item for each i (sum of all m for that i) try the following:

```
public List<decimal> getTotalSellingPrice(int costSheetID) 
{
    List<decimal> totalSellingPrice = new List<decimal>();
    decimal bothMarkupAndToms = 0;
    foreach (var i in getMarkupPrice(costSheetID)) 
    {
      bothMarkupAndToms = i;
      foreach (var m in getToms(costSheetID)) 
      {
          bothMarkupAndToms += m;                      
      }
      totalSellingPrice.Add(Math.Round(bothMarkupAndToms));   
    }
    return totalSellingPrice;
}
```

I hope that help

**Edit:**

I think you are try to add corresponding elements from those two lists, for example first element from markup prices with first element from toms and so on. Based on that scenario you want something like bellow:

```
public List<decimal> getTotalSellingPrice(int costSheetID) 
{
    List<decimal> totalSellingPrice = new List<decimal>();
    decimal bothMarkupAndToms = 0;
    List<decimal> markupPriceList = getMarkupPrice(costSheetID);
    List<decimal> tomsList = getToms(costSheetID);
    for(int i = 0 ; i < tomsList.size() ; i++)
    {
      totalSellingPrice.Add(Math.Round(markupPriceList[i] + tomsList[i]));   
    }
    return totalSellingPrice;
}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks but the same problem still remains where as it should only return 4 values as there is only 4 values in each of the lists. Still returning 16 values. So it should add values from markup and toms list together then add to the final list.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your 2 foreach loops. You're creating `i * m` values with your code instead of matching `i` to `m` and then adding them. For each `i` you get 4 `m` so 4 * 4 will give you 16 values.

Comment: Could you elaborate? Why is it multiplying? When i explicitly applied addition?

Comment: you are looking for 4 values but end up with 16. that is because u run through 2 foreach loops. 4 values in i and 4 values in m.

Comment: basically in your first foreach you loop through "i" and then you loop through all "m" values and add i+m. that will give u 4 values. now when you come back to the i loop your at i+1 and you repeat the entire process. after 4 iterations you are at 16 values.